# Why is my mocked list not removing a certain element?

Tags: c#, linq, moq

For one of my assignments I've had to make a method that will return the next item from a database using IRepository as a base. I'm using a TDD design cycle, and so far, this is what I have:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ShouldReturnNextExportRequest()
    {
        var requests = new List<ExportRequest>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var exportRequest = new Mock<ExportRequest>();
            exportRequest.SetupGet(req => req.Id).Returns(i);

            requests.Add(exportRequest.Object);
        }

        // Over-writing variables is bad
        requests = requests.OrderBy(er => er.Id).ToList();

        /**
         * Mock the IRepository so that the Min() call returns the export request with the minimum Id
         */
        var repo = new Mock<IRepository<ExportRequest>>();
        repo.Setup(rep => rep.Min(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<ExportRequest, int>>>()))
            .Returns<Expression<Func<ExportRequest, int>>>(expr => requests.Min(e => e.Id));

        repo.Setup(rep => rep.Get(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns<int>(requests.ElementAt);
        repo.Setup(rep => rep.Delete(It.IsAny<ExportRequest>()))
            .Callback<ExportRequest>(req => Assert.IsTrue(requests.Remove(req), "Couldn't remove {0} from list", req.Id));


        var exportRequestRepository = new ExportRequestRepository(repo.Object);
        exportRequestRepository.GetNextRequest();
        exportRequestRepository.GetNextRequest();

        var third = exportRequestRepository.GetNextRequest();
        var top = requests.First();
        Assert.AreEqual(top.Id, third.Id, "Top element in list has id of {0}, but return from repository is {1}", top.Id, third.Id);
    }
```

The `GetNextRequest()` method simply does this:

```
    public ExportRequest GetNextRequest()
    {
        var top = _exportRequestRepository.Min(er => er.Id);
        var element = _exportRequestRepository.Get(top);
        _exportRequestRepository.Delete(element);
        return element;
    }
```

It all works perfectly fine, however the second element - with an id of 1 - is never removed from the list. I've worked this out to be down to the `IEnumerable.Min` implementation on `List`, as when it never seems to return an element with Id of 1 (determined by looking at the List in debug mode).

Am I missing something obvious?

NOTE:
I'm using a mocked IRepository from SharpRepository. Not that it makes a difference, as a Moq-ed interface has no inherent actions, but it's worth noting.

EDIT: test output.

```
Test Name:  ShouldReturnNextExportRequest
Test FullName:  ExportService.Tests.ExportRequestRepositorySpecification.ShouldReturnNextExportRequest
Test Source:    c:\Users\dan.pantry\Desktop\RUMM\ExportService.Tests\ExportRequestRepositorySpecification.cs : line 17
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.211873

Result Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<1>. Actual:<3>. Top element in list has id of 1, but return from repository is 3
Result StackTrace:  at ExportService.Tests.ExportRequestRepositorySpecification.ShouldReturnNextExportRequest() in c:\Users\dan.pantry\Desktop\RUMM\ExportService.Tests\ExportRequestRepositorySpecification.cs:line 49
```

EDIT2: So I put a Callback on Get() like so:

```
        repo.Setup(rep => rep.Get(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns<int>(requests.ElementAt)
            .Callback<int>(req => Console.WriteLine("Retrieved {0}", req));
```

And now my output looks a bit like this:

```
Retrieved 0
Retrieved 1
Retrieved 1
```

EDIT3: Here is the origin of _exportRequestRepository in `GetNextRequest()` - In the test it's the mocked Repository and is injected into the constructor

```
    public ExportRequestRepository(IRepository<ExportRequest> exportRequestRepository)
    {
        _exportRequestRepository = exportRequestRepository;
    }
```

Comment: Where is _exportRequestRepository defined? I'm assuming that's used in the Setup method? In the test you refer to a local exportRequestRepository but in GetNextRequest you use _exportRequestRepository?

Comment: Sorry, I appreciate the names are confusing. _exportRequestRepository is the repository injected into the ExportRequestRepository constructor. Basically, _exportRequestRepository is the mocked SharpRepository IRepository<ExportRequest> injected into my more specific repository, ExportRequestRepository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved.
The problem was that I was using `ElementAt` when I should have been using `Find`, and that I was calling `First()` before `GetNextRequest()` (get next request "pops" the elements from the underlying repository - will probably change that, though).

```
        var repo = new Mock<IRepository<ExportRequest>>();
        repo.Setup(rep => rep.Min(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<ExportRequest, int>>>()))
            .Returns<Expression<Func<ExportRequest, int>>>(expr => requests.Min(e => e.Id));

        repo.Setup(rep => rep.Get(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns<int>(i => requests.Find(er => er.Id == i));

        repo.Setup(rep => rep.Delete(It.IsAny<ExportRequest>()))
            .Callback<ExportRequest>(req => Assert.IsTrue(requests.Remove(req), "Couldn't remove {0} from list", req.Id));


        var exportRequestRepository = new ExportRequestRepository(repo.Object);

        Assert.AreEqual(0, exportRequestRepository.GetNextRequest().Id);
        Assert.AreEqual(1, exportRequestRepository.GetNextRequest().Id);

        var top = requests.First();
        var third = exportRequestRepository.GetNextRequest();

        Assert.AreEqual(top.Id, third.Id, "Top element in list has id of {0}, but return from repository is {1}", top.Id, third.Id);
```

Solved code is as above. As you can see, `Get` now uses `requests.Find()` rather than `requests.ElementAt`